# Loading SQL files which contain deliminators using PHP

Tags: php, mysql-workbench

I successfully use the below run_sql_script() function to execute SQL in a file using PHP.

```
    static public function run_sql_script($script)
    {
        // Load and explode the sql file
        $f = fopen($script,"r+");
        $sqlFile = fread($f,filesize($script));
        $sqlFile=preg_replace("/\\\;/", '&#59', $sqlFile);   //replace semicolons with ascii
        $sqlArray = explode(';',$sqlFile);
        //Process the sql file by statements
        foreach ($sqlArray as $stmt)
        {
            if (strlen($stmt)>8)
            {
                //Used to prevent blank lines at end of sql script from executing
                $stmt=preg_replace("/&#59/", ';', $stmt);   //replace ascii with semicolons
                try {db::db()->exec($stmt);}
                catch(PDOException $e){library::sql_error($e,$stmt);}
            }
        }
        return;
    }
```

I generate the SQL using MySQL Workbench, and recently, I added a trigger also through MySQL Workbench.  It added the following SQL to the file.

```
DELIMITER $$

CREATE TRIGGER tg_contacts_upd AFTER UPDATE ON contacts
FOR EACH ROW
.... 
BEGIN
END$$

DELIMITER ;
```

Upon running the new file through my run_sql_script() function, I now get the following error.

> Error in query: DELIMITER $$ CREATE TRIGGER tg_contacts_upd AFTER
>   UPDATE ON contacts FOR EACH ROW BEGIN END$$ DELIMITER SQLSTATE[42000]:
>   Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL
>   syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version
>   for the right syntax to use near 'DELIMITER $$ CREATE TRIGGER
>   tg_contacts_upd AFTER UPDATE ON contacts FOR EACH ' at line 1

Any suggestion how to fix

Answer (score 1):

Seems too easy, but the following appears to work.

```
    static public function run_sql_script($script)
    {
        $sql = file_get_contents($script);
        db::db()->exec($sql);
    }
```